# How can I do a WHERE clause across 2 rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **store_i table**

```
store_id, open_247
996, 0
```

> **store_period table**

```
store_id, day, opentime, closetime
996, 3, 00:00:00, 04:00:00
996, 3, 08:00:00, 23:59:59
996, 4, 00:00:00, 04:00:00
996, 4, 08:00:00, 23:59:59
```

In PHP I'm determining the current time, current day, time 30 minutes from now, and the day 30 minutes from now:

```
currenttime: 23:42:01
currentday: 3
timeplus30: 00:12:01
dayattimeplus30: 4
```

I'm trying to determine whether a store is open now and will be open in 30 minutes.

For the example data above, the store_id 996 should be considered open because of rows 2 and 3 of store_period.

I want to retrieve a store_id for any store that either has open_247 = 1, or has a row that fits the currenttime and currentday and a row that fits the timeplus30 and dayattimeplus30.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT store_i.store_id
FROM store_i 
WHERE store_i.open_247 = 1 
UNION 
SELECT store_i.store_id
FROM store_i 
JOIN store_period 
ON store_i.store_id = store_period.store_id 
WHERE ((CAST('23:42:01' AS TIME) >= opentime 
AND CAST('23:42:01' AS TIME) <= closetime 
AND store_period.day = 3) 
AND (CAST('00:12:01' AS TIME) >= opentime 
AND CAST('00:12:01' AS TIME) <= closetime 
AND store_period.day = 4))
```

It returns no result for the example above, which is unexpected.

I think it's because no single row satisfies both conditions in the where clause of the 2nd union clause.

**The 2 conditions (open now, open in 30 minutes) must be satisfied. In this example they are satisfied across 2 rows, but they could be satisfied twice by the same row. How can I check such conditions?**

I thought about doing it with another union, but it seems that would return a row even if only 1 condition is met (for example if it's open now, but not open in 30 minutes).

I think I need to somehow do a where clause across 2 rows, or find some other way to do it.

Comment: You don't explain how `day` is used, but it seems important.

Comment: `WHERE` does a very specific thing - it applies the stated condition to each row individually, and keeps the row in the resultset if and only if the condition is true.  So there is no "`WHERE` clause across 2 rows", and you're right that you need something different.  There are many ways.  With all due respect, this is pretty obviously homework, and we don't know what SQL constructs your class is currently covering, so I don't think you're going to get a satisfactory answer here.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger You mean the problem can't be solved in SQL, and I have to do separate queries and figure it out in PHP?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The day rolls over at midnight, so if the timeplus30 is on the same day, the day will be the same. This is worked out in PHP, and my only problem is how to do the where clause over 1-2 rows.

Comment: @Gimmethe411 - The problem absolutely can be solved in SQL.  But again, we're not in a position to know whether that's the expected solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like :

```
SELECT store_i.store_id
FROM store_i 
WHERE store_i.open_247 = 1 
    or (store_i.store_id in (
        SELECT store_i.store_id
        from store_period 
        where CAST('23:42:01' AS TIME) >= opentime 
        AND CAST('23:42:01' AS TIME) <= closetime 
        AND store_period.day = 3)
    and 
        (SELECT store_i.store_id
        from store_period 
        where CAST('00:12:01' AS TIME) >= opentime 
        AND CAST('00:12:01' AS TIME) <= closetime 
        AND store_period.day = 4)
    )
```

Comment: I added JOIN clauses inside the 2 sub-SELECT clauses, because store_id is in store_i, not in store_period, and then it works.

Comment: You right, I made a mistake.  But Store_id is in store_period table (from what you poseted first).  It should works if you do subselect like (select store_period.store_id....)

Comment: Oh yes, that's even better, so I don't need any join clauses. Thanks